# Returning a structure from a function

Tags: c++

I am trying to learn structures, but I am confused why I can't see changes in the structure after returning it from my function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct multiset {
    vector <int> elements;
    vector <int> counts;
};

multiset multiset_add(multiset Set, int num) {
     Set.elements.push_back(num);
     return Set;
}

int main()
{
    multiset Set;
    multiset_add(Set, 2);
    cout << Set.elements[0];
    return 0;
}
```

If I would add the `cout << Set.elements[0]` inside the function after pushing a number into the set, it would print 2, but It won't print 2 after returning it, why is that?

Comment: `Set = multiset_add(Set, 2);`? or pass argument by reference...

Comment: tip: learn functions first. The issue is not caused by returning a `struct`, but by using the function wrongly. You'd have same issue with `int square_it(int x) { int y= x*x;  return y;}`

Comment: `Set` is passed by value, so a copy is modified and returned by `multiset_add()`.   `main()` does not retrieve the returned struct.    Change `multiset_add(Set, 2)` to `Set = multiset_add(Set, 2)`.    The fact that a variable in `main()` has the same name as an argument of `multiset_add()` does not magically link the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function

```
multiset multiset_add(multiset Set, int num) {
     Set.elements.push_back(num);
     return Set;
}
```

gets the parameter `Set` passed by value. You either have to use the returned `multiset` in you main function like this:

```
int main()
{
    multiset Set;
    Set = multiset_add(Set, 2);
    cout << Set.elements[0];
    return 0;
}
```

Or you can pass the parameter by reference, so it can be modified inside the function like this:

```
void multiset_add(multiset& Set, int num) {
     Set.elements.push_back(num);
}
```

A raw pointer would also be possible, but a reference is the preferrable option.

Answer (score 2):

Your main function should be like this to work the way you designed it:

```cpp
int main()
{
    multiset Set;
    Set = multiset_add(Set, 2);
    cout << Set.elements[0];
    return 0;
}
```

In your original code, you are never using the return value of multiset_add !

But, in fact, you should rather use pointers to not create a copy of your set.

Comment: "should" it be like this? Maybe OP wants to modify the `Set` in main, not a copy of it